# Is it true that $z(z^3-1)/(z^3-1)$ is regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. I have a map $h:\mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2: z\mapsto (z^3-1,z(z^3-1))$ and a map $t:\mathbb{A}^2\rightarrow K: (x,y)\mapsto y/x$. I am asked if the composition is regular.

$(t\circ h)(z) =  z(z^3-1)/(z^3-1)$. Clearly this is regular if $z\neq 1$. When $z = 1$, I say that there exist polynomials $f(z) = z, g(z) = 1$ such that $f(z)(z^3-1) = g(z)z(z^3-1)$ for any $z\in\mathbb{A}^1$. Hence $f/g = z(z^3-1)/(z^3-1)$ for any neighborhood of $1$.

I conclude that the composition is regular, but I am afraid that what I wrote is not correct and I may be dividing by zero in some way. Is what I am doing correct? Why or why not? Can you give me some intuition on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, what you are doing is completely correct. Tiny nitpick: "Clearly this is regular if $z \neq 1$." What if (say in the complex case) $z = \exp(2 \pi i/3)$? But that does not change the fact that what you are doing is correct.